# OpenLayers and KML support

Tags: openlayers, kml

I would like to know if OpenLayers (let's say v5.3.1 for example) is able to display BalloonStyle informations of a KML file (i.e. the text, images, links attached).

Here is an example of a very simple KML file like the ones I would like to use:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<kml xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2">
  <Document>
    <Style id="style0">
      <LineStyle>
        <color>ff000000</color>
        <width>1</width>
      </LineStyle>
      <BalloonStyle>
        <text>
            <![CDATA[
                <p>This is a fault<br /><br />
                <img style="height:100px;" src="http://www.ipgp.fr/~klinger/page_web/images/images_terrain/big_pushup_koko01.jpg"/></p>
            ]]>
        </text>
      </BalloonStyle>
    </Style>
    <Folder>
      <name>Calque 1</name>
      <Placemark>
        <styleUrl>#style0</styleUrl>
        <LineString>
          <coordinates>
            -61.6926474431735,16.2341653330369,0
            -61.6694171297468,16.2124434871456,0
            -61.673339087593,16.192531686805,0
            -61.6615730696896,16.1846876267478,0
            -61.6615730696896,16.1608538685609,0
            -61.6211463129778,16.1527082304885,0
            -61.6311019966009,16.1382269998943,0
          </coordinates>
        </LineString>
      </Placemark>
    </Folder>
  </Document>
</kml>
```

Thanks a lot for your help!

Answer (score 0):

OpenLayers can handle KML, it's demonstrated in multiple examples on the OpenLayers website.

[This one](http://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/kml.html) is close to what you want, it overlays the date over an OSM map and shows additional information when hovering features.

To show ballon-bubbles with information, you can use an `Overlay`. Of course, there is also an example for that: [Overlay Example](http://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/overlay.html).

Just combine the two and you have KML features with popups